# Label's format in barchart different from the corresponding cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, formatting, charts

I have stacked bar chart. In the label's format I checked "linked to source".
Now in the datacell,l I have this custom format "[>999999]#.##0,00.." M$";[>999]#.##0,00." k$";#0,00$". The problem is that the number in the chart label is different :

```
Example : for 1 000 000 I get

1.0M in the cell (that's what I wanted)
1000000,000,, M$ in the chart label (that's my problem)
```

Is it a bug in Excel ?

Answer (score 2):

My system uses a decimal point and a comma as the thousand separator. When I adjust the custom format accordingly, both the cell and the data label formats are fine. BUT if I swap the symbols for decimal and thousand separator, I see what you see. To me this looks like a bug, as if the linked to source data labels assume a number format like 1,000.00 and cannot adjust to 1.000,00

I manually applied custom format

[>999999]#,##0.00,," M$";[>999]#,##0.00," k$";#0.00$

to one data series and it shows fine. Note that it's the decimal point format

I then manually applied the decimal comma format

[>999999]#.##0,00.." M$";[>999]#.##0,00." k$";#0,00$

and while still in the dialog it gets changed to

[>999999]#.##000.." M$";[>999]#.##000." k$";#,000$

The decimal comma gets removed. That looks like a bug. Mind you, I only changed the decimal and thousand separator for Excel, not for the whole system. I'll try that when I find the time.